# Update based on subquery fails

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I am trying to do the following update in Oracle 10gR2:

```
update
  (select voyage_port_id, voyage_id, arrival_date, port_seq,
    row_number() over (partition by voyage_id order by arrival_date) as new_seq
   from voyage_port) t
set t.port_seq = t.new_seq
```

Voyage_port_id is the primary key, voyage_id is a foreign key. I'm trying to assign a sequence number based on the dates within each voyage.

However, the above fails with **ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view**

What is the problem and how can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't update subqueries with `row_number`, you'll have to calculate the row number in the `set` part of the update.  At first I tried this:

```
update voyage_port a
set a.port_seq = (
  select 
    row_number() over (partition by voyage_id order by arrival_date)
  from voyage_port b
  where b.voyage_port_id = a.voyage_port_id
)
```

But that doesn't work, because the subquery only selects one row, and then the `row_number()` is always 1.  Using another subquery allows a meaningful result:

```
update voyage_port a
set a.port_seq = (
  select c.rn
  from (
      select 
        voyage_port_id
      , row_number() over (partition by voyage_id 
            order by arrival_date) as rn
      from voyage_port b
   ) c
  where c.voyage_port_id = a.voyage_port_id
)
```

It works, but more complex than I'd expect for this task.

Comment: The second statement does indeed work! And I agree, it looks a bit complex compared to my original attempt/syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can update some views, but there are restrictions and one is that the view must not contain analytic functions.  See [SQL Language Reference on UPDATE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/statements_10008.htm#i2067715) and search for first occurence of "analytic".

This will work, provided no voyage visits more than one port on the same day (or the dates include a time component that makes them unique):

```
update voyage_port vp
set vp.port_seq =
( select count(*)
  from voyage_port vp2
  where vp2.voyage_id = vp.voyage_id
  and vp2.arrival_date <= vp.arrival_date
)
```

I think this handles the case where a voyage visits more than 1 port per day and there is no time component (though the sequence of ports visited on the same day is then arbitrary):

```
update voyage_port vp
set vp.port_seq =
( select count(*)
  from voyage_port vp2
  where vp2.voyage_id = vp.voyage_id
  and (vp2.arrival_date <= vp.arrival_date)
  or (   vp2.arrival_date = vp.arrival_date 
     and vp2.voyage_port_id <= vp.voyage_port_id
     )
)
```

Comment: OK, that is probably the problem then. Any idea as to what I can do to rewrite the update statement ?

Comment: @Tony: "in your original SQL, the sequence of ports visited on the same day is arbitrary" - no, the arrival_date includes both date and time, and the order by in the analytic function makes sure it's not arbitrary

Comment: OK, in that case my simpler code will work for you too.  I was assuming the dates had no time component.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think you can update a derived table, I'd rewrite as:

```
update voyage_port
set port_seq = t.new_seq
from
voyage_port p
inner join
  (select voyage_port_id, voyage_id, arrival_date, port_seq,
   row_number() over (partition by voyage_id order by arrival_date) as new_seq
   from voyage_port) t
on p.voyage_port_id = t.voyage_port_id
```

Comment: Could be, but whatever it supports he'll have to put the actual table to update the update clause, not the derived table

Comment: Actually, Oracle does support this syntax. See http://www.psoug.org/reference/update.html under "Update the results of a SELECT statement"

Answer (score -2):

The first token after the UPDATE should be the name of the table to update, then your columns-to-update. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the select statement where it is, but you can' *update* the result set from the select legally.
A version of the sql, guessing what you have in mind, might look like...

```
update voyage_port t
set t.port_seq = (<select statement that generates new value of port_seq>)
```

**NOTE:** to use a select statement to set a value like this you must make sure only 1 row will be returned from the select !

EDIT : modified statement above to reflect what I was trying to explain. The question has been answered very nicely by Andomar above

Comment: Somewhere in there you have to join the result of the subquery to main table, other the db won't know which 'new_seq' to assign to which parent row.

Comment: Actually, Oracle does support this syntax. See http://www.psoug.org/reference/update.html under "Update the results of a SELECT statement"

Comment: Codewerks has a point, I've edited my answer to more accurately reflect what I was trying to say. FWIW